# Access to reading system controls via javascript (epub3 media overlay)

Tags: javascript, overlay, media, epub3

i'm currently working on a epub3 project that will use Media Overlay.

I would like to add 2 buttons on each page, one for playing a song, and one for playing and a cappella version of this song using text highlighting with media overlay.

Is there any method to access the reading device controls via javascript to trigger something like that ? In other words, I would like to lauch the read-aloud by clicking a button and not directly with the device controls.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: no, there is no reliable, cross-platform way to do that. (By "cross-platform" I mean "that works on any arbitrary reading system".)

The long answer is: the EPUB specification does not require the reading system (RS) to expose Javascript capabilities. For those RS'es that do have JS capabilities, the EPUB specification does not require them to support "manipulation" of their state. Plus, the EPUB specification requires each Content Document (i.e., XHTML file) to be associated with at most one SMIL file, while you would need to create two: one referencing the full audio file, the other referencing the a capella audio file. So, on paper, there is no way to do what you want.

In practice, the only RS that offers JS handles to control Media Overlays is iBooks (see the iBooks Asset Guide). But it would work only on iBooks, and only for Fixed Layout (pre-paginated) rendition.

If you would like to code your own Media Overlay emulation JS library, you might have a look at https://github.com/pettarin/rb_smil_emulator . Note, however, that I myself deprecated its use, as it is a very fragile approach.

Comment: Hi Alberto, thank you very much for your answer.

I checked the iBooks Asset Guide and found a solution to my problem by adding ibooks:readaloud="startstop" on my button, and it works.

I needed to have one button to trigger the read-aloud functionnality, because I want to add style on it, and this solution, even if it only works on iBooks (that's what i want), is perfect.

Thanks again !